# Shaped JDialog: Dragging in JTextField causes window to move

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-6

I'm using a transparent (shaped) JFrame under Java 6 with Mac OS X.

My system tells me that Translucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT is supported.
Although my system tells me that Translucency.PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT is not supported, I found out it works under Mac OS X when putting pixels with alpha=0.

Now, when selecting text in the JTextField, it also drags the window as if I would drag on the underlying contentpane.

here my sample code to try (contains main-method to run on your computer)

```
import com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DialogTest extends JFrame {

    public DialogTest() {
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {
                if (g1 instanceof Graphics2D) {
                    Paint p =
                            new GradientPaint(0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(240,240,240, 0),
                            0.0f, getHeight(), new Color(240,240,240, 255), true);

                    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g1;
                    g2d.setPaint(p);
                    Shape s = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
                    g2d.fill(s);
                }
            }
        };

        add(p1);
        p1.setOpaque(false);
        p1.add(new JButton("button 1"));
        JTextField tf = new JTextField("Sample Text To Select");
        p1.add(tf);
        p1.add(new JButton("button 2"));

        setUndecorated(true);       
        setSize(400,400);
        AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        // Create the GUI on the event-dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DialogTest tw = new DialogTest();

                // Display the window.
                tw.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


   }
}
```

Comment: Very important.  Because your panel `p1` is transparent, you MUST be calling `super.paintComponent` or you could end up with any number of really bad paint problems...

Comment: Also, since, I think Java 1.4 or there abouts, Graphics is guaranteed to be an instance of `Graphics2D`...

Comment: Sure you completely right. I wrote it very fast to demonstrate just the problem..:)

Comment: I don't think they relate to your problem, just feedback

Comment: I noticed that Mac OS X doesn't paint the shadow of the window anymore, but by calling

getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.windowShadow.revalidateNow", ""+((new Random()).nextInt()));

each time the window is repainted, it works. This could be also an add on to your really great tutorial on how to create transparent windows in the other thread.

Comment: I'd say that the shadow is part of the decoration of the frame border...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.  3) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278531/418556) for ideas.

Comment: sorry... hope it is a better SSCCE now