# How to show only JLabel hiding JFrame or any lower level container

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency, jlabel

I want to show JLabel but want to hide JFrame border and other lower level containers like JPanel.
It just JLabel displayed on the screen.

I tried window transparency but following piece of code hides everything if trying to work with window opacity.
On decreasing windowOpacity , even JLabel becomes blurred. I tried with JPanel as well but couldn't get exact output.
I want this behaviour in jdk1.6 only
I want the JLabel content to be visible properly without any opacity impact but backbround must be purely transparent.

```
     public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sanjaal Corps - Windows On Top Demo!");
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setLocation(100, 150);        
        com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame,0.4f);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(new JLabel("TESTING"));       
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I tried with solution provided 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/140041-make-a-jpanel-transparent-to-see-the-desktop-behind/

But the problem here is if we minimize or maximize the window , then a constant color being set, So found its not the best solution or may say the Perfect one.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I added all the contents inside main , so now pasted the entire class

Comment: `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities`  That is very fragile.  You say.. *"I want this behaviour in jdk1.6 only"* ..but that will not work in a non-Oracle JRE.  BTW - Why JDK and not JRE?  Your users have the JDK?

Comment: sorry that a wrong choice of word , I meant jre only , yeah I agree the rt.jar for jre1.6 restricted the access but I just wanted to see the behavior and wanted to explain what I actually want. I tried with AlphaComposite as well but couldn't fullfill the exact requirement

Comment: Why are you wasting my time?  `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is
 decorated`  That code is rubbish, and it is not whatever code you have been running.  I repeat, **for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**  An SSCCE should include imports, and show the same behavior here as it does there.  Also, for transparency, ignore those (accursed) `com.sun` classes and look to the public API as seen in [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) or..

Comment: .. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278531/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson nice answer you referenced ... though the api you used is not available in java6, going com.sun is the only way that I know of, might be wrong, of course

Comment: @AndrewThompson Except import I believe that code works and I already mentioned yes I shouldnt have used AWTUtlities but I just wanted to show the example of my expected behaviour. and thanks for your reference

Comment: not sure what you are asking: how do you _want_ the label to be shown? As is, it's behaving just as expected (with the overall opacity set to transparent) And if you have problems related to min/max the frame, you should add that functionality to your example, so we can easily reproduce it. BTW: the link you referenced just shows a blank page ..

Comment: I wanted to show JLabel content with complete transparent background . thats the bottomline. Link is working at my side , don't know whats the problem with link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand your requirements correctly...

I typically add a transparent panel to the `Window`.  This means that, generally, the transparency properties of the `Window` don't then effect the child components, for example...

[image]

Generally speaking, there are now two ways to make a window transparent.

1. Under Java 7, you simply make it's background color transparent.
2. Under Java 6 (update 10+), you need to use the unofficial `com.sun.AWTUtilities` class

...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TransparentWindow02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TransparentWindow02();
    }

    public TransparentWindow02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                setOpaque(frame, false);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Click me if you can see me");
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this).dispose();
                }
            });
            add(label);
        }

    }

    public static void setOpaque(Window window, boolean opaque) {

        String version = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
        if (version.startsWith("1.7")) {
            window.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        } else {
            try {
                Class<?> awtUtilsClass = Class.forName("com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities");
                if (awtUtilsClass != null) {

                    Method method = awtUtilsClass.getMethod("setWindowOpaque", Window.class, boolean.class);
                    method.invoke(null, window, opaque);

                }
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to show the *foreground*, of the label (nothing else) that is its text/icon, you would set the frame's opacity to false:

```
com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(frame, false);
```

The usual caveat against using com.sun.** classes, which unfortunately is the only way to reach transparent windows prior to java7