# Any method like setOpacity that works with JWindow

Tags: java, swing, frame, jwindow

I was just wondering if there was any method that was like **setOpacity(float);** that worked with the JWindow. I've tried the setOpacity method but it seems like it doesn't work with JWindows because I get the following error when trying to use the method

> The method setOpacity(float) from the type Window is not visible

Here is the code in my main method.

```
JWindow window = new JWindow();
window.setSize(100.100);
window.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: See how you go with [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278531/418556)..  It uses an undecorated frame (which is indistinguishable from a `JWindow`).

Comment: I want a JWindow because it doesn't show that icon in the bar when ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  But there is something else you can do.

Start by taking a look at [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

[image]

```
public class TranslucentWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TranslucentWindow();
    }

    public TranslucentWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JWindow window = new JWindow();
                window.setSize(100, 100);
                window.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated**

Confirmed operation under Windows 7 and MacOS X, Java 7

[image]

**Updated**

Try and a check to see if translucent is actually supported...

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge
        = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();

boolean isUniformTranslucencySupported
        = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isPerPixelTranslucencySupported
        = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSLUCENT);
boolean isShapedWindowSupported
        = gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(PERPIXEL_TRANSPARENT);

System.out.println("Hello");

if (isUniformTranslucencySupported && isPerPixelTranslucencySupported && isShapedWindowSupported) {

    // Build window as normal...

} else {

    if (!isUniformTranslucencySupported) {
        System.err.println("Translucentancy is not support");
    }
    if (!isPerPixelTranslucencySupported) {
        System.err.println("Per Pixel Translucentancy is not support");
    }
    if (!isShapedWindowSupported) {
        System.err.println("Per Pixel Transparenancy is not support");
    }

    System.exit(0);

}
```

Comment: When running the code it flashes red then looks like this. http://i.imgur.com/EqtwEvd.png

Comment: @user2612619 What version of Java are using?

Comment: 7, using Eclipse IDE on linux.

Comment: @user2612619 Sounds like a bug under linux